# Why does the cache need to be cleared to affect any hook_menu() change?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook-menu

I create simple module to test hook_menu() function

```
my_menu()
{
    $item["abc"] = array(
    "title"=> t("abc")
    "page callback"=> "my_page");
    return $item;
}
```

Whenever I change "title" of item (to "ABC for example"), I wonder why the cache needs to be cleared to take affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because menus are cached for performance reasons. Building the site's menus takes a hefty amount of processing, which would slow down the site if done on every pageview.

Comment: I found that when we use alias url (like article/myhouse instead of node/5) and when we call arg(1) it return 5 instead of myhouse.Can you explain it for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arg()` gives you the internal Drupal arguments, it ignores aliases.